# Get All Magento Images for Product (with original sizes)

Tags: php, magento

Right now I'm trying to loop through each of a products images, and output their fullsize image url, and the images sizes.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>
    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image')->getOriginalHeight(); ?>
    <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image')->getOriginalWidth(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Trying to figure out why this returns the main images size for every image.

This code doesn't work at all

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->getOriginalWidth(); ?>
```

Neither does this...

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getOriginalWidth()); ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! Apparently ->getOriginalWidth and ->getOriginalHeight do not work on other main images.

Used this to workaround it

**PHP**

```
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
    <?php $fullImage = new Varien_Image($_image->getPath()); ?>
        <?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>'
        <?php echo $fullImage->getOriginalWidth(); ?>
        <?php echo $fullImage->getOriginalHeight(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I'm interested in feedback on this solution. Is this not efficient? Doesn't seem to impact performance at all so far.